# Facebook Data Retention Policy and Message Deletion

Tags: database, facebook, messaging, overwrite, retention

If a message or the whole thread is deleted on Facebook Messenger from both ends or in case of a group chat all ends is this content considered deleted? I mean will it be removed somehow like overwritten or anonymized over time? What will be left out of those messages server data then beacause I guess the total removal is not a thing?

I guess that data should be overwrite or anonynimzed but I dont know if deleting chat on both ends only marks the messages as hidden or something

Comment: Are you asking what data Facebook might still be storing on their end (very likely, I'd say, _all_ of it), or whether you should do any clean-up on your end?

Comment: I mean what happens when both users delete the conversation between each other? I know its stored on the server but what happens after users delete that, are they stored there indefinetely?